# How to run a series of vim commands from command prompt

Tags: shell, vim, command-prompt

I have four text files A.txt, B.txt, C.txt and D.txt
I have to perform a series of vim editing in all these files.
Currently how I am doing is open each files and do the same vim commands one by one.

Is it possible to make a script file which I can run from the command prompt, means without open the actual file for vim editing.

for example, if I have to perform the below vim commands after opening the A.txt file in vim editor:

```
:g/^\s*$/d
:%s/^/[/
:%s/\(.*\)\(\s\+\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1
:%s/$/]/
:%s/design/test/
```

Is it possible to make a script file and put all these commands including `gvim A.txt` (first command in the file).
and edit run the script file from command prompt.

If it is possible, please let me know how to do it and how it can be done with single or multiple files at a time?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
vim -c <command> Execute <command> after loading the first file
```

Does what you describe, but you'll have to do it one file at a time.

So, in a windows shell...

```
for %a in (A,B,C,D) do vim -c ":g/^\s*$/d" -c "<another command>" %a.txt
```

POSIX shells are similar, but I don't have a machine in front of me at the moment.

I imagine you could load all the files at once and do it, but it would require repeating the commands on the vim command line for each file, similar to

```
vim -c "<command>" -c "<command>" -c ":n" (repeat the previous -c commands for each file.)  <filenames go here>
```

EDIT: June 08 2014:
Just an FYI, I discovered this a few minutes ago.

vim has the command bufdo to do things to each buffer (file) loaded in the editor.  Look at the docs for the bufdo command.  In vim, `:help bufdo`

Comment: vim -c "<command>" -c "<command>" -c ":n" (repeat the previous -c commands for each file.)  <filenames go here>

this is what I meant
thank a lot ...

Comment: dont forget `-c ":wq"` at the end.

Answer (score 36):

The  amount of `-c` commands directly passed to Vim on the command-line is limited to 10, and this is not very readable. Alternatively, you can put the commands into a separate script and pass that to Vim. Here's how:

### Silent Batch Mode

For very simple text processing (i.e. using Vim like an enhanced 'sed' or 'awk', maybe just benefitting from the enhanced regular expressions in a `:substitute` command), use *Ex-mode*.

```
REM Windows
call vim -N -u NONE -n -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Note: silent batch mode (`:help -s-ex`) messes up the Windows console, so you may have to do a `cls` to clean up after the Vim run.

```
# Unix
vim -T dumb --noplugin -n -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Attention: Vim will hang waiting for input if the `"commands.ex"` file doesn't exist; better check beforehand for its existence! Alternatively, Vim can read the commands from stdin. You can also fill a new buffer with text read from stdin, and read commands from stderr if you use the `-` argument.

### Full Automation

For more advanced processing involving multiple windows, and real automation of Vim (where you might interact with the user or leave Vim running to let the user take over), use:

```
vim -N -u NONE -n -c "set nomore" -S "commands.vim" "filespec"
```

Here's a summary of the used arguments:

```
-T dumb           Avoids errors in case the terminal detection goes wrong.
-N -u NONE        Do not load vimrc and plugins, alternatively:
--noplugin        Do not load plugins.
-n                No swapfile.
-es               Ex mode + silent batch mode -s-ex
                Attention: Must be given in that order!
-S ...            Source script.
-c 'set nomore'   Suppress the more-prompt when the screen is filled
                with messages or output to avoid blocking.
```

Comment: Nicely explained. Is there any switch to write the output to a file.
I tried with -w, -W, :w but of no help.

Comment: @EashwarGadanchi: Typically, you would `:write` the contents, either to the input file, or a different file name, so Vim acts as a filter, like an advanced `sed` or `awk`. In silent batch mode (what is described as "full automation", you can also use `:print` to output individual lines and `:verbose echomsg <MSG>` to output arbitrary text; these will be printed to standard output (which you can redirect into a file).

Comment: Why `--no-plugin` in place of `-u NONE`? It seems like for Unix you can start with `-N -u NONE -n -es -T dumb`. I'm not sure what each of those add though. Not what they do, but if they make difference. Well, some of them most likely do. By the way it's not clear which part must be given in specific order. Oh, only `-es`.

Comment: @x-yuri: At the end I mention that both can be used; it depends on the use case. `-u NONE` is completely independent from user settings, `--no-plugin` avoids a time-consuming load of plugins, but keeps the user's main settings (as the out-of-the-box defaults are not very friendly). If you do need plugins, both can be omitted as well, but this then has the most coupling to your config.

Answer (score 26):

With all the commands you want to run on each file saved in a script, say "script.vim", you can execute that script on one file like this (as others have mentioned):

```
vim -c "source script.vim" A.txt
```

Taking this one step further, you can save your file at the end of the script, either by putting a `:w` command inside the script itself, or passing it from the command-line:

```
vim -c "source script.vim | w" A.txt
```

Now, you can run any command in Vim on multiple files, by using the `argdo` command. So your command turns into:

```
vim -c "argdo source script.vim | w" A.txt B.txt C.txt D.txt
```

Finally, if you want to quit Vim after running your script on every file, just add another command to quit:

```
vim -c "argdo source script.vim | w" -c "qa" A.txt B.txt C.txt D.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following syntax:

```
ex foo.txt <<-EOF
  g/^\s*$/d
  %s/^/[/
  %s/\(.*\)\(\s\+\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1
  %s/$/]/
  %s/design/test/
  wq " Update changes and quit.
EOF
```

The `ex` command is equivalent to `vim -E`. Add `-V1` for verbose output.

Alternative one-liner syntax is for example:

```
ex +"g/^\s*$/d" +"%s/^/[/" +"%s/design/test/" -cwq foo.txt
```

To load commands from the file, use `-s cmds.vim`.

You can also use [shebang for Vim to parse the file from the argument](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5229/467).

For more examples, see:

- [How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467)
- [BashFAQ/021](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021)

Answer (score 2):

JimR and Ingo have provided excellent answers for your use case.

Just to add one more way to do it, however, you could use my vimrunner plugin to script the interaction in ruby: https://github.com/AndrewRadev/vimrunner.

Example:

```
vim = Vimrunner.start

vim.edit "file.txt"
vim.insert "Hello"
vim.write

vim.kill
```

This can be useful for more complicated interactions, since you get the full power of a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Use `vim -s ...` to script not only colon commands, but also normal-mode commands such as `=` for formatting:

1. Create a file with all keystrokes that you want vim to execute.
2. Run `vim -s SCRIPT-FILE FILE-TO-EDIT`

For example: Let's say you want to use vim's `=` command to re-indent all the lines of `myfile.html`. First, using vim itself, make a file named `myscript` that has this:

```
gg=G:wq
```

(`gg` moves to the top of the file; `=G` re-indents from the current location to the end of the file; `:wq<Enter>` saves the file and exits.)

Then, run this to have vim launch, edit `myfile.html`, and save it:

```
vim -s myscript myfile.html
```