# Is there a way to let vi run editing commands in a file?

Tags: vim, vi

Let's say I have a file "edit_commands" with some editing commands, like:

```
:1,$s/good/better/g
:1,$s/bad/worse/g
```

Is there a way to let vi load and run the commands in "edit_commands"?

Update:
It appears the "-S" option can be used for this. Refer to:
[How to run a series of vim commands from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235112/how-to-run-a-series-of-vim-commands-from-command-prompt)

Comment: FYI, there is also a dedicated [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) if you don't get a good answer here.

Comment: Thank you so much. Was not aware of that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a series of vim commands from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235112/how-to-run-a-series-of-vim-commands-from-command-prompt)

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you would want to use a program like sed which shares a
common ancestor with vi (i.e. the 'ed' editor) for such a task:

```
sed -i 's/good/better/g; s/bad/worse/g' your_file
```

See this great [sed tutorial](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Is there a reason you need to use vi to do it? You could use perl if you need more advanced regex capabilities.

Comment: This can be a workaround for some cases. However, the regex engine in sed is fairly weak (even with GNU extended).

Comment: @JoeSmith You could use perl if you need advanced regex capabilities (but I don't know it well enough to give a perl based answer)

Answer (score 3):

The solution in Perl may look this way:

```
perl -i.old -pe 's/good/better/g || s/bad/worse/g' your_file
```

The `-i.old` option saves a copy of your old file under the name `your_file.old`, what can be very useful when bad comes to worse and worse comes to worst...

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Will give it a shot.